# iText: How to force a table row to start on a new page?

Tags: java, itext

How to to force a table row (or its first cell) to start on a new page in iText (Java)?

I have a `PdfTable` with two columns and I am adding `PdfCell`s to it. Now I need to force the 3rd row (or 6th cell) to start on a new page without having to finish my table and start a new one.

Comment: Why *without having to finish my table and start a new one*? Isn't that the obvious solution?

Comment: Because columns need to align exactly without fixed width.

Comment: If that is the requirement, ok (even though I do not know a reason for such a requirement). I have no good idea, though, to solve this. You can, of course, first render the table as a whole on some temporary medium (e.g. a throw-away document), read the column widths, and then create the actually used tables page by page using those column widths. But this appears somewhat complicated...

Comment: *Because columns need to align exactly without fixed width.* Er... columns *always* have a fixed width, even if you don't define one. I should know, because that's how I designed iText. Unless of course you are converting HTML to PDF, but nothing in your question points in that direction.